# Need to Remove Duplicate from List

Tags: java

I have a list of objects in ArrayList.I want to remove the duplicate object in the list based on old paymentDate.For an Example, if the member (Vishal) repeated two times I need to remove the Vishal object based on old paymnetDate from the list.

```
[{CreditCardNum,name,Amount,DueDate,PaymentDate}]

masterlist = [{4123456789123456,Vishal,80000,03/06/2015,07/06/2015},
              {4123456789123456,Vivek,80000,07/06/2015,11/06/2015},
              {4123456789123456,Vishal,80000,03/06/2015,09/06/2015}];


Removable Object from List = 
  {4123456789123456,Vishal,80000,03/06/2015,07/06/2015}

List<CreditcardVo> masterlist =new ArrayList<CreditcardVo>();
public class CreditCardVO {
   public String creditNumber;
   public String name;
   public int  amount;
   public Date dueDate;
   public Date paymentDate;
   public String getCreditNumber() {
          return creditNumber;

   }
   public void setCreditNumber(String creditNumber) {
          this.creditNumber = creditNumber;
   }
   public String getName() {
          return name;
   }
   public void setName(String name) {
          this.name = name;
   }
   public int getAmount() {
          return amount;
   }
   public void setAmount(int amount) {
          this.amount = amount;
   }
   public Date getDueDate() {
          return dueDate;
 }
   public void setDueDate(Date dueDate) {
          this.dueDate = dueDate;
   }
   public Date getPaymentDate() {
          return paymentDate;
   }
  public void setPaymentDate(Date paymentDate) {
      this.paymentDate = paymentDate;``
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried anything yourself? If so, please share the code and explain what did not work. If not, why not?

Comment: Derive the CreditCardVO from Comparable, and define your own equals and hashCode methods (based on the date, which is your uniqueness criterion). Subsequently add all CreditCardVO records to a HashSet, and afterwards extract the unique payment records from that HashSet.

Comment: @FlyingDutchman I believe the _uniqueness criterion_ is by name but the OP wants to keep the object with the latest payment date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the algorithm that you can use to do that:
First You need a unique identifier for each of the object in the ArrayList. The identifier can me the name if you are sure that the name does not repeat.

- Step 1: Create an empty map where the key is the object identifier and the value will be the object itself
- Step 2: For each element, in ArrayList :

  - Check if the map contains the identifier of the object
  - If yes then get the value `val` associated to that identifier in the map and compare it its date with the date of your current object `curr`:

    - if `val` has the latest date then do nothing
    - if `curr` has the latest date then call `map.put(identifier, curr)` to update the value in the map
  - If no, then `map.put(identifier, curr)` to add the current object to the map

At the end, the result will be the values of the map. And you can get that by using `map.values()`

Comment: Thanks MigSena. I think it will work .However i will try and let you know if i face any issues .

Comment: Good way to answer a "homework" question without giving away the solution in code!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method as such:

```
List<CreditCardVO> getDistinctObjectsByName(List<CreditCardVO> cardVOS){
         Collection<CreditCardVO> resultSet = 
          cardVOS.stream()
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(CreditCardVO::getName, Function.identity(),
                         (left, right) ->
                             left.getPaymentDate().after(right.getPaymentDate()) ?
                                  left : right
                 )).values();
         return new ArrayList<>(resultSet);
}
```

which given a list of `CreditCardVO` will return a new list with distinct objects with the latest payment date.

Comment: Hi Aomine, Thanks for your updates . Could you please explain this in Java 6 Since we need to use Java 6 to remove the duplicates.

Comment: @VetriSelvan can you confirm if the _uniqueness criterion_  is by name or due date ? and you should have included that exact comment in your post otherwise how would anyone know what you can or cannot use?

Comment: Something go like this
for(int i=0;i<masterlist.size();i++)
{
for(int j=i+1;j<masterlist.size();j++)
{
  if(masterlist.get(i).getname().equal(masterlist.get(j).getname())
{
   long l1=msaterlist.get(i).getpaymentDate().getTime();
   long l2=masterlist.get(j).getpaymentDate().getTime();
     
}

}
}